# how to horizontally align kitchen sink cards in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to align me kitchen sink cards horizontally here is a picture of the cards.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JIXc.png)

These cards ⬆️ are not aligned horizontally as you see I want them aligned horizontally I tried many CSS & HTML codes but none worked.

This is one line of code I tried:

CSS: float:left;clear:none;

Comment: Welcome! Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

on parent element, to horizontally centered the item. There are other values also for justify-content which you can use to align as you want.

In bootstrap, you can simply use classes:-

```
d-flex justify-content-center
```

on parent element, to horizontally centered the item. Similarly there are other classes also. You can see bootstrap docs.

Comment: None of these worked for me don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a css property called `display: flex;` i that the default flex direction is row is already enabled. so you can use this property for your cards main root element.